# ccmake. vs ccmake [path]

Tags: linux, macos, cmake

I am trying to wrap my head around Linux/Ubuntu (installed and using it just today for first time...), coming from OSX. 
I am compiling a program, and the instructions for compiling state to use ccmake. in the trunk folder. My Ubuntu terminal does not recognize "ccmake." (it did in OSX), only "ccmake trunk". Is that the same as calling "ccmake." in the trunk folder in OS? 
Is ccmake. supported in Linux at all? I have make, cmake and gui-curses-cmake running, and have done $ sudo apt-get install build-essential –y .

The thing that confuses me a little is that "ccmake trunk" places the make file in the main folder, not in trunk. 
ccmake. in OS put that into the trunk folder. Sure, I can move the file(s), but it makes me wonder if there is a difference...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Usually you call `ccmake .` or `cmake .` (note the space) in the directory where your *CMakeLists.txt* is located. That's because the dot is the first argument for the command. If you omit the space the shell will search for a binary called `ccmake.` (including the dot) in your *PATH* but won't find any. I can't tell you why `ccmake.` (without the space) works on OSX but I guess it has something to do with their shell.

Comment: Scai, many many thanks. That saved my weekend - indeed, the space was the thing. Not even sure anymore whether I used one in OSX or not. 
No matter now, it works in Linux. 
Cheers!!